# Woocommerce Checkout page error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Hi I've been facing an issue on my website avcpetstore.com

-theme used in this is (Porto ecommerce theme)

**I've tried the following steps already.**

- disabling all plugins (doesn't workout)
- disabling current theme and activation other 2 themes (doesn't workout)
- Php memory limit increased already- permalinks setup multiple times (did't workout)
- all other things in terms of debug did't workout.console showing

**Browser's console showing this error**
Unable to fix malformed JSON
checkout.min.js?ver=7.0.0:1  ---------- Unable to fix malformed JSON

Answer (score 1):

Hello I solve this after I dezactivate Enable Cross-Sells
[image: cross-sells disable]

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your checkout page file while copy-paste code you miss clicked and remover or added symbol like '<' so you should review code from end to start looking for unintended content. Also you could try disabling (commenting) all the hooks to that file one by one, maybe there is mistake in them.

Also you can try using the default woocommerce template file to see if it start working again and trying adding your custom code on top of your fresh default file.